# How to make this kind of circle shape in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make the following shape:

[image]

As you can see, it's a circle, but the top side is cut.

Can this be done in Flutter?

This is how I'm making a circle shape:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    height: 150,
    width: 150,
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
        this.text,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 20,
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    ),
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      gradient: new LinearGradient(
        colors: [
          const Color(0xFF1A1864),
          const Color(0xFFFF5357),
        ],
        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        stops: [0.0, 1.0],
        tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: @VinayHP What do you need to know?

Comment: Show some code..

Comment: @VinayHP I added the code I'm using to make a circle shape.